# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a question related to the state.extra in Flutter.
I want to pass null value to the player's profile page, so it will display 0.

Right now I have declared extra that doesn't allow me to pass null value.
What could be the best solution for this problem?

```
                    GoRoute(
              path: 'settings',
              pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                  final map = state.extra as Map<String, dynamic>;
                  final score = map['score'] as Score;

                  return buildMyTransition<void>(
                    child: SettingsScreen(
                      score: score,
                      key: const Key('settings'),
                    ),
                    color: context.watch<Palette>().backgroundPlaySession,
                  );
                },
```

Error message

Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast)

Comment: final map is not null safety

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to cast a null value, here state.extra is null. Make sure to have state.extra some value or add a check of not null condition

Answer (score 2):

Your error is saying that `state.extra` could return a `null` value, and if that was the case then the code execution would be "`null as Map<String, dynamic>;`" hence the error.
In this case you need to add `?` to make it null-safe:

```
final map = state.extra as Map<String, dynamic>?; //can now be map = null
```

and now since `map` could return null, you need to adjust your `score` to check if the value is null and what should it be if so. for example:

```
final Map<String, dynamic> score = map != null 
                      ? map['score'] as Score 
                      : {'score' : 0};  //or just 0
```

In this example, you are setting `score = {'score' : 0}; //or 0` if the result of `map?['score']` is null

Comment: Thank you very much! I have one follow-up question: I defined score as int?, but still getting the error 
_TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Score' in type cast)'

Comment: sorry about that, i had done the same mistake as you did in my example where it could execute "null as Score" if map returned null. I edited my answer to fix that

Comment: i can't see your full code so i changed 0 (int) to a map type in my example but you can put in whatever your use case is